# How to handle exception in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using AsyncTask like this

```
public class AccountReportActivity extends Activity {

private OrgaLevelTask orgaLevelTask;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {            
        ......
        orgaLevelTask  = new OrgaLevelTask(AccountReportActivity.this, spinner_orgaLevel, spinner_branch, txt_extra, txt_extra1);               
        orgaLevelTask.execute();

    } //end of onCreate

} //end of class AccountReportActivity
```

task:

```
public class OrgaLevelTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<OrgaLevel>> {

    //Constrcutor
    public OrgaLevelTask(AccountReportActivity accountReportActivity, Spinner spinner_orgaLevel, Spinner spinner_branch, TextView txt_extra, TextView txt_extra1) {

        this.accountReportActivity = accountReportActivity; 
        this.spinner_orgaLevel = spinner_orgaLevel;
        ....                
    } //end of constructor

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<OrgaLevel> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {       
        return callWebService();        
    } //end of doInBackground()

    private ArrayList<OrgaLevel> callWebService() {

        try {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            ......
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {                 
             Toast.makeText(accountReportActivity, "Service is not connected, Please make sure your server is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             return null;                                   
        }  catch(Exception e) {             
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println();                               
        }
    } //end of callWebService()

} //end of class OrgaLevelTask
```

My this task call another AsyncTask which has the same code. The problem is if server is running then everything fine. But if server is not running and i call the web service then i get the exception that **Force Application close**. Why? I am handling **SocketTimeoutException** IF exception happens then i am saying that show toast on my Activity but why it is force closing the application. How can i handle it? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are hitting the right exception, in your case SocketTimeoutException? Maybe try to add the top level class Exception and print the stacktrace to find what exception occurs exactly..

Comment: Full logcat output always require while asking question on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the internet connection this way first

```
public static boolean checkConnection(Context context) {

    final ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    final NetworkInfo netInfo = mConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
 }
```

In this method

```
       // Checking the internet connection
        if (!InternetConnectionCheck.checkConnection(this)) {
            Utilities.alertDialogBox(this, R.string.Title_String,
                    R.string.No_Internet_connection_String);
        } else {
           orgaLevelTask  = new OrgaLevelTask(AccountReportActivity.this, spinner_orgaLevel, spinner_branch, txt_extra, txt_extra1);               
           orgaLevelTask.execute();
        }
```

Comment: the problem is with the specific host being unavailable(ie, the server being unavailable) , not the internet.

Comment: i am getting error at line `final NetworkInfo netInfo = mConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();`...`AndroidRuntime(389): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception`  . Why i am getting this ?

Answer (score 2):

you should not use use `Toast` in `doInBackground`

```
 catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {                              

   Toast.makeText(accountReportActivity, "Service is not connected, Please make sure your server is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  //<----------------------
```